# OpenCV: Problem at creating a Skeleton of Lines

Tags: computer-vision, opencv, morphological-operations, morphology

I need to get the lines from a photographie of a sheet of paper. While recherching, I came along [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16665742/a-good-approach-for-detecting-lines-in-an-image), where one answer referred to [this blog entry](http://felix.abecassis.me/2011/09/opencv-morphological-skeleton/).
Now I am having trouble with this approach. I have implemented it as follows (with the c++-interface of OpenCV:

```
// the image has to be grayscale
if (image.channels() != 1)
{
    cv::cvtColor(image, image, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
}

// we need to enhance the lighting before we can threshold the photography
cv::equalizeHist(image, image);
// a binary image is needed
cv::threshold(image, image, threshold, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY);
cv::imwrite("thresholdedImage.jpg", image);

// the resulting skeleton
cv::Mat skeleton(image.size(), CV_8UC1, cv::Scalar(0,0,0));
// needed if in-place processing is not possible
cv::Mat temp(image.size(), CV_8UC1);
// eroded image is saved here
cv::Mat eroded;
// needed for morphological transforms (erodation, dilation)
cv::Mat element = cv::getStructuringElement(cv::MORPH_CROSS, cv::Size(3,3));

bool done = true;
int i = 0;
while(done)
{
    // eroding + dilating = opening
    cv::erode(image, eroded, element);
    cv::dilate(eroded, temp, element);
    cv::subtract(image, temp, temp);
    cv::bitwise_or(skeleton, temp, skeleton);
    eroded.copyTo(image);

    done = (cv::countNonZero(image) == 0);
    ++i;
}
```

For proof of concept, I decide to use a computer-made drawing for testing purposes, to eliminate issues with lighting at this early stage. This can be seen here:
[image: Created with GIMP]
The threshold is correct, but unfortunately the skeleton looks very strange: 
[image]
I have drawn the skeleton after 100 iterations, where it looked like this:
[image]

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: That looks like the right skeleton (to the first 100 iterations) of the bright background area. Have you tried inverting the image?

Comment: Now I have tried, and it works! May you post this as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

You are actually drawing the skeleton of the background (brighter region).

change

```
cv::threshold(image, image, threshold, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY);
```

in your codes to

```
cv::threshold(image, image, threshold, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY_INV);
```

You should be able to get the right skeleton.

Answer (score -1):

You could well refer [here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/3207/what-is-a-good-thinning-algorithm-for-getting-the-skeleton-of-characters-for-ocr/) for a few different implementations, which provide acceptable results.